# How to get inferred type of dynamically returned value based on passed Zod schema object?

Tags: typescript, zod

I have a function that randomly returns one of these objects:
`{ name: "Tommy", age: 15 }`
`{ car: "BMW" }`

Let's say I want to run this function and hope that it returns me the User object instead of the Car. To verify this I want to pass it Zod schema as an argument so the function will parse it and throw an error if the random object doesn't match my schema.
Otherwise, if the random object matches schema, I want to get this object returned from the function with the inferred type so I know that i have `name` and `age` properties.

That's my code:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const User = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number()
});

const randomObjects = [
  {
    name: "Tommy",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    car: "BMW"
  }
];

export const getRandomObject = (
  Schema: z.AnyZodObject
): z.infer<typeof Schema> => {
  try {
    const obj = Math.random() > 0.5 ? randomObjects[0] : randomObjects[1];

    Schema.parse(obj);

    return obj;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Sorry, wrong Schema passed");
  }
};

const user = getRandomObject(User);
console.log(user);
```

`user` is being inferred as `{ [x: string]: any; }`.
How to make typescript know that it is an User object with `name` and `age` properties?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zod-v3g3hp?file=/src/index.ts:513-735

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using a generic parameter so that TS can infer the schema type and reuse it:

```
export const getRandomObject = <S extends z.AnyZodObject>(
  Schema: S
): z.infer<S> => {
```

[Forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zod-forked-vz30k8)